# AngularJS ng-repeat in tbody not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have problem with using ng-repeat in tbody.
When i use that code:

```
<tbody>
   <tr ng-repeat="group in groups">
      <td>{{ group.name }}</td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

I get this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'childNodes' of undefined

But having this code:

```
<div ng-repeat="group in groups">{{group.name}}</div>
```

Inside the same scope works perfect. I've found some answers to use ng-repeat on tbody, but i need this structure to use jquery datatables on this. Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: can you provide the jsfiddle for the error ?

Comment: seems something really silly to be honest. Give me a little more code to see where you might be going wrong. Have a look at this plunk (https://plnkr.co/edit/KcZiBiY4s9TPASYIg0eB)

Comment: Sorry, i don't know how to use all this fiddle-like stuff. Here is more code: https://plnkr.co/edit/nDRj7T9Cy5hugqQLEhM3?p=catalogue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this, its working

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
   $scope.groups = [
        {name: 'Michał', users:  5, owners: 4},
        {name: 'Michał', users:  5, owners: 4},
        {name: 'Michał', users:  5, owners: 4},
        {name: 'Michał', users:  5, owners: 4}
    ];
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script data-semver="1.4.9" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.9/angular.js" data-require="angular.js@1.4.x"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="plunker" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    using div
  <div ng-repeat="group in groups">{{group.name}}</div>
  using table
   <table>
  <tbody>
  <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>name</th>
                            <th>user</th>
                            
                        </tr>
                    </thead>  
 <tr ng-repeat="group in groups">
      <td>{{ group.name }}</td>
       <td>{{ group.users }}</td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
</table> 

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: I can't use static controllers. I use ng-view for multipages so this way won't works.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access "group.name"

If "groups" is your scope array name, ensure that "name" is your array element.
From the error that you are getting, I presume your array element name is not same as you are trying to access.
Eg:

app.js:

```
var app = angular.module('testing', []);

app.controller('mainctrl', function($scope) {
$scope.groups = [
{name: 'Apple'},
{name: 'Orange'},
{name: 'Banana'}
];
});
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="testing">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Testing</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
<script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.9/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="mainctrl">
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat='group in groups'>
    <td>{{group.name}}</td>
  </tr>
  </table>
  </body>
  </html>
```

hope it helped. :)